# AzureDevOps Pipeline - UWP - Error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppInstallerFile' failed. Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline task whose YAML is as describe below:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)"  /p:AppxBundle=Always  /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly  /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="$(signingCert.thumbprint)" /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)" /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(signingCert.password)" /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true  /p:AppInstallerUri="$(AppInstallerUri)"  /p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency=1 /p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun'
    platform: x64
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    restoreNugetPackages: true
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    createLogFile: true
```

Basically here I am trying to create appbundle and generate the appinstaller file so I can distribute the app using the link as the app is an internal app.

This was working till 14th May absolutely fine. However when we are running the pipeline again it give us below error. I am sure AzureDevOps build must have been definitely update something in there agent. But not able to figure out the actual issue.

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6361,5): Error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppInstallerFile' failed. Input string was not in a correct format.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6361,5): error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppInstallerFile' failed. Input string was not in a correct format. [D:\a\1\s\Inspection.Management.UWP\Inspection.Management.UWP.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6361,5): error APPX0002:  [D:\a\1\s\Inspection.Management.UWP\Inspection.Management.UWP.csproj]
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(6361,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateAppInstallerFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()

   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.LogError(String context, String fileName, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 columnNumber, String message, Tuple`2 callerInfo, Object[] messageArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.LogError(String message, String callerMemberName, Int32 callerLineNumber, Object[] messageArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppInstallerFile.ExecuteImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.Execute(String file)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.Execute(String file)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Has any face this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here.

This works if we disable GenerateAppInstallerFile by setting it to false in the MSBuild Arguments as follows.

`/p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=False`

This is needed only if we need to publish our app to a Web server, then we need to tell MSBuild to generate a versioned .appinstaller file. Otherwise, for my case, I don't need it so I simply set it to false and the pipeline works now.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I need to publish my app to webserver, therefore I need to generate version .appinstaller file.

Comment: Then you may need to have additional information (as shown in Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/azure-dev-ops)

/p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=True
/p:AppInstallerUri=http://yourwebsite.com/packages/ /p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun /p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency=1

Comment: If you see my msbuild args in my question, it covers all the required parameters mentioned in Microsoft docs.

Comment: I had this exact issue.

Last successful build: May 26, image version 20210516.0, VS+MSBuild version 16.9.
First failed build: May 27, image version 20210525.0, VS+MSBuild version 16.10.

Turning off GenerateAppInstallerFile is at least a temporary workaround.

Comment: Interestingly - a local MSBuild with 16.10 seems to be fine. Comparing the logfiles for local-vs-Pipelines using v:diag, the inputs to the GenerateAppInstallerFile task are identical (other than pathnames). Really weird...

Comment: We have the same issue. Would appreciate if MSFT would provide opt in mechanisms for some of their devops changes as opposed to forcing it down our throats.

Comment: Still awaiting the resolution any one got any solution other than making /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=False ?

Comment: @HitenDamania This could be caused by an issue with the Visual Studio version installed on the agent. The fix is pending release: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Publish-of-Windows-Application-Packaging/1435655

Comment: Thanks everyone for help issue has been resolved by Microsoft, details are in this link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Upgrade-to-1610-break-pac/1435154